# Solve Keil µVision 5 error: Load "STM32F7-DISCO\\STM32F7-DISCO.axf"

Tags: c

I am using Keil µVision 5 and STM32F7-Disco.
I can not open the debug session due to this error:

> could not Load file "STM32F7-DISCO\STM32F7-DISCO.axf"

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Check the compilation log. Maybe it is this kind of error: _The size of this image (xxxx bytes) exceeds the maximum allowed for this version of the linker_?

Comment: Fix grammar and format.